# Lucene.Net versions and may skipping optimize(for lucene 3.0.3)?

Tags: .net, lucene

We’re working on a search engine in .Net and using the Lucene.net libraries.
While indexing, we hit some slowness and when googling about this, we saw that there was some enhancements in this area in a higher version than what we’re using.

It looks like the highest .Net version for Lucene is 3.0.3 while in Java the version is much higher.

Does anyone know of a higher .net version for Lucene? Does java Lucene versions are the same for Lucene .net versions?

We have quite a lot of data that we need to index so we’re unsure whether it will be wise to completely skip the Optimize step (for 3.0.3 lucene version).
Also, anyone knows what happens if we do not call Dispose on the Writer when we finish working with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Lucene.Net 4.8 is in beta now, [check it out here](http://code972.com/blog/2016/07/98-lucene-net-4-8-is-in-beta-and-we-need-your-help).
- Yes, the intent is for the Lucene.Net version to be largely identical to the same version of Lucene.
- You can probably survive get by without Optimize. Optimizing will generally make searching a bit faster, but it's quite an expensive operation. If you are indexing your whole data set, and it will remain largely static after that point, it may be a good idea because it will optimize search efficiency for the current state or the index. It's *not* recommended after writing just a few documents. The stuff optimize does is handled on the fly, in the background, by the writer's MergePolicy. If your data is constantly changing and being updated, you could just let the MergePolicy do it's thing. In 4.8, optimize is replaced with `ForceMerge`, to be a be more explicit (and less enticing) about what it does.
- You should always call `Dispose` when you are done with the writer. If you don't your changes may not be commmited, and the lock not on the index may not be released.

Comment: Hi,

First thanks for your answer!

I have one more question:

Must I run the optimize (or ForceMerge as you mention above) right after the indexing?
I mean I want to run the indexing, commit and close the writer, then to open writer on the same path and run optimize on it.

Will it be effective?

Comment: @Hadassa - Yes, running it later (after committing, closing and reopening) would work fine.

Comment: I ended up here because my calls to `ForceMerge` didn't do anything. This answer and & comments made me realize that you must call it _after_ commit. The sequence `commit,close,reopen, forceMerge, [commit,] close` did the trick